# Protege very slow when loading music ontology

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, protege

I'm using Protege version 5.2.0 and I'm trying to add the music ontology from http://purl.org/ontology/mo/ . I've downloaded the rdfs on my computer, and when I try to import the file on my ontology, it takes forever to load.
In particular, it freezes when loading "http://purl.org/ontology/similarity/": now it has been there for like 10 minutes, and every time I have to brutally close the program, otherwise it won't stop loading.
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import [The similarity ontology](http://kakapo.dcs.qmul.ac.uk/ontology/musim/0.2/musim.html) first.
Probably, better from a local file:

[image: Ontology imports]